# ACR122u stop detecting SmartPhone

Tags: nfc, pcsc

I am developing an prototype for my dissertation. i was using  ACR122u reader/writer, passing APDU command to pass data to android phone  (HTC One M7). before i applied the last patch (6.09.401.5) ACR122u  was detecting smartphone but after that it has stopped

Earlier i just used to activate NFC on smartphone and ACR122u will turn from red green signalling it has been detected.

please looking for some guidance

with regards

Answer (score 1):

Probably "Auto PICC polling" was disabled due to the update, or the particular tag type is ignored during PICC polling. You could try to reset the PICC operating parameters to the default value (0xFF), either using a program to access your ACR122U reader provided by ACR or by using the following program.

```
public class ResetReader {
    public static final int FILE_DEVICE_SMARTCARD = 0x310000;
    public static final int IOCTL_CCID_ESCAPE_SCARD_CTL_CODE = 
                                        FILE_DEVICE_SMARTCARD + 3500 * 4;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // the following loop lists all connected card terminals
        TerminalFactory factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
        for (CardTerminal term : factory.terminals().list()) {
            System.out.println(term.getName());
        }

        // connect to the ACR122U by choosing the correct name
        CardTerminal terminal = factory.terminals().getTerminal("ACS ACR122 0");
        Card c = terminal.connect("DIRECT");
        c.transmitControlCommand(IOCTL_CCID_ESCAPE_SCARD_CTL_CODE,
            new byte[]{(byte)0xFF, 0x00, 0x51, (byte)0xFF, 0x00});
    }

}
```